# CSS entire sprites image is loaded

Tags: css, sprite

I am new to CSS sprites and trying to use them on firefox.
The problem is when I load sprite on  tag or any  tag, it shows entire sprite image on page.

I tried using text-indent = -9999px also but that didn't help. The image was still shown on top of rest of page. Using z-index didn't help either.

```
#container{
background: url(csg-50e22b073c545.png) no-repeat top left transparent;
overflow: hidden;
}
.bulletform{
background-position: 0 - 1567px;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
}
```

So, my questions are:
1. How to avoid displaying entire sprite image?
2. Can I just load sprite image once on say  or some root DIV tag for page? and then use background-position to show individual images at relevant places?

Please help.

Comment: Could you make an jsfiddle with html?

Comment: Please, a JSFiddle would be nice.

Comment: I haven't tried jsfiddle before but it looks interesting. Not sure how to use it though with drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you use sprites. You shouldn't load it into any top level wrapper. Instead, set background image for each element that should use sprite and adjust background position. Browsers are wise enough to only load the same image once, no matter how many times you call it in your CSS.

Comment: Thanks Voitkek for response. I will try it tonight and will let you know if the issue is resolved.

Comment: I tried one image on sprite and it seems to be working great. Thanks Voitek. :)